# Adding NULL value to row in KNIME

Tags: knime

Does anyone know if it is possible to add a null value to a row in KNIME?

I am trying to use the Rule Engine to remove some values, and substitute them with a NULL.

Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is [no syntax](https://github.com/knime/knime-core/blob/3.4.0/org.knime.jsnippets/src/org/knime/base/node/rules/engine/BaseRuleParser.java#L1019-L1067) (as of KNIME 3.4.0) for declaring missing values from Rule Engine nodes. There are workarounds though:

1. When you specify which case should have non-missing values, the non-matching rows [will be missing](https://www.knime.org/files/node-documentation/org.knime.base.node.rules.engine.RuleEngineNodeFactory.html):

   > If no rule matches, the outcome is a missing value.
2. You can have a column with all-missing values with the proper type and set that column as the outcome, like `... => $missingIntCol$`

With the [`Rule Engine (Dictionary)`](https://www.knime.org/files/node-documentation/org.knime.base.node.rules.engine.twoports.RuleEngine2PortsNodeFactory.html) node [the outcome column cannot contain missing values](https://github.com/knime/knime-core/blob/3.4.0/org.knime.jsnippets/src/org/knime/base/node/rules/engine/twoports/RuleEngine2PortsNodeModel.java#L293).)

Answer (score 0):

Create a Dummy Null Column with a Rule Engine First and then use another rule engine to program what you need
EG. $Example Column$ = "#"  =>$Dummy Null"  This will replace your # in the Example Column with Null Values

Hopes it helps

Answer (score 0):

There is `missingValue()` function in [Column Expressions](https://hub.knime.com/knime/nodes/Column_Expressions*2_0ji_xeG-SudFu-) node which returns missing value in a cell. Column Expressions node is based on JavaScript syntax so following logic is possible:

```js
if(column("column1")=="someValue") //create missing
{ 
    missingValue()
} 
else //take value from colum1
{ 
    column("column1")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a normal 'Java Snippet': Create the input and output via the lower menu. If you chose the 'replace' option for the output column you can replace the input values directly. Otherwise you have create a new column.

Here is example java code to paste and edit:

```
if(c_your_input>100)
{
    out_your_input = c_your_input;
}
```

If the there is no matching with if clauses missing values are automatically created.